# BibLaTeX in TeXstudio - bib file not updated, even when running BibLaTex explicitly

Tags: biblatex, compiling, texstudio

I'm using BibLaTeX (in TeXStudio) to generate a .bib file. Even when I explicitly run BibLaTex (Tools > Bibliography, in TeXStudio; Bibliography is set to BibLaTeX), my citations do not update unless I delete the .bib file, forcing it to create a new .bib file. Is there a way to avoid this?

The pertinent aspects of my code:

```
documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}  
\begin{filecontents}{cites.bib}

%generic citation, as an example
@ARTICLE{NameYear,  
    author = {Name},
    title = {Sciencey Title Here},
    journal = {Science},
    year = {2016},
    volume = {1},
    pages = {1--5},
    number = {16},
    doi = {10.1002/xx.2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{cites}
\begin{document}
Example Text.\cite{NameYear}.

\section*{\centering{References}}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Added to code to make compilable.

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable, e.g. add a documentclass and `\begin` and `\end{document}`? Do you get any warnings or error messages when compiling?

Comment: I tried with `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=none, citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}  
\begin{filecontents}{cites.bib}

%generic citation, as an example
@ARTICLE{NameYear,  
    author = {Name},
    title = {Sciencey Title Here},
    journal = {Science},
    year = {2016},
    volume = {1},
    pages = {1--5},
    number = {16},
    doi = {10.1002/xx.2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{cites}
\begin{document}

Example Text.\cite{NameYear}.

\section*{\centering{References}}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}` and this works fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I assume by deleting the `.bib` file you mean deleting the `.bbl` file?  Can you check what is executed when running `BibLaTeX`.  [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is a package, to generate citations you should be using either `biber` (preferred) or `bibtex` with the `backend=bibtex` being passed to the  [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package.

Comment: @samcarter This compiles fine for me, but if I compile, then add a reference, compile latex, compile bibliography, and compile latex, my new reference does not appear.

Comment: @DaiBowen  I meant the cites.bib file generated, but it's possible that deleting the .bbl would also work. I checked the log, which says: This is BibTex, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2010)

Comment: You are remembering to run `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex` in order to make updated citations appear in the PDF as per [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162)

Comment: Are you using `filecontents` in your actual document? Without having `\usepackage{filecontents}`, existing files will not be overwritten.

Comment: @DaiBowen In TeXstudio, I was running: Build & View, Bibliography, Build & View, Build & View 

@TorbjørnT. I did not have `\usepackage{filecontents}` in my actual document! I've added it now, and this fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably not normal to use the `filecontents` environment to generate the `.bib` file, but if you want to have everything contained in one file, it is fine.

However, in the default implementation of the environment there is one important caveat: If the file already exists, nothing happens. In other words, the file will not be updated.

Getting around that is easy though: Add `\usepackage{filecontents}` before your `filecontents` environment, this packages redefines the environment so that files are updated.